# php login: undefined index

Tags: php

Im very new to php and this is my first go on on this login.
so when im typing in a valid username and password from the database im getting these two errors:

Notice: Undefined index: brukernavn on line 3

Notice: undefined index: passord on line 4

```
$username = $_POST['brukernavn'];
$password = $_POST['passord'];

if($username&&$password)
{

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("prosjekt") or die ("Cant find db");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bruker WHERE brukernavn='$username'");

$radnum = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($radnum!=0)
{

while ($rad = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $dbuser = $rad['brukernavn'];
    $dbpass = $rad['passord'];
}

if ($username==$dbuser&&$password==$dbpass)
{
echo "Logged in";
}
else
    echo "Wrong username or password";

}
else
    die("That user does not exist!");


}
else
    die("Please enter a username and password!");




?>
```

Could anyone see where i went wrong here?

Comment: You should read this topic for best practices for a login script: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/73024/what-best-practices-should-be-employed-in-a-php-login-script

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access two variables that haven't been assigned yet:

```
$username = $_POST['brukernavn'];
$password = $_POST['passord'];
```

You either:

1. Need to wrap your login code in an `if` statement to check to see if the form has been submitted
2. Need to check to see if those variables are set before accessing their values

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```
 <?

$username = $_POST['brukernavn']; 
$password = $_POST['passord'];

if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) { // on form submit... make sure the html form input submit is name='submit' then this script will work

    if($username&&$password)
        {

        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("prosjekt") or die ("Cant find db");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bruker WHERE brukernavn='$username'");

        $radnum = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if ($radnum!=0)
                {

                while ($rad = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    $dbuser = $rad['brukernavn'];
                    $dbpass = $rad['passord'];
                }

                if ($username==$dbuser&&$password==$dbpass)
                {
                echo "Logged in";
                }
                else
                    echo "Wrong username or password";

                }
            else
                die("That user does not exist!");


        }
    else
        die("Please enter a username and password!");

    }


?>
```